# Book about an “alien abduction”

Tags: story-identification, novel, alien-abduction

I read this book around 2008 in high school.

It was about a young man in the 70’s or 80’s that enlisted in the army. On his way to his base, he saw some bright lights/orbs floating in front of his car while driving in the highway at night. These lights got closer to him, to the point that he blacked out. He then “woke up” in a different place; the last thing he could remember was those lights. He looked around and looked at a mirror and he was old, like around 35 years old.

Close to the mid-end of the story, it was revealed that in reality he was not abducted, but hypnotized by his girlfriend and his friend, who plotted to control him through hypnosis and take over his family’s money. His girlfriend ended up marrying him while hypnotized, to inherit the money, but was secretly involved with this other friend.

Hope y’all can help me out with this one. Thanks!